# How to add a new sub directory to CakePHP installation

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, directory

I have CakePHP installed on the root of a website and want to add a new directory with other content. So it looks like this right now: www.cakephpsite.com and I also want www.cakephpsite.com/directory.

But when I create a new folder on the root the website doens't go to that folder I just created, instead it goes to the path app/View/WrongDirectory.

I never used CakePHP before so I'm sorry if this  is very basic and any help would be helpful.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

So CakePHP is expecting the files to be in the app/webroot folder.  So the .htaccess file you are showing redirects EVERYTHING to app/webroot. That means you need to put your new directory in the app/webroot folder so it would be app/webroot/directory and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, it do work, but the website redirects the adress from www.cakephpsite.com/directory to www.cakephpsite.com/app/webroot/directory in the adress bar. Is there any way to avoid this to happen?

Comment: @mah2602 are you on a shared host or do you have access to edit your virtual host file. If you can change your virtual host file to point to app/webroot it would solve your problems

Comment: I only have access to the cakephp instalation folder via ftp.